# Running VB.NET application on Windows 2003 server

Tags: vb.net, performance

I've developed a VB.NET application with Visual Studio 2008. The application communicates with SQL Server and processes a text file.

My question is about performance. While I run it from Visual Studio 2008, it takes 3 sec to complete. The same is when
I run the executable created by the Setup Wizard on my desktop (Windows XP sp 3).
But if I run the executable installed on a Windows 2003 Server, it takes 15 sec to complete!
What could be the reason of degrading performance on the server vs. the desktop?
The .Net framework 3.5 SP1 is installed both on the desktop and the server.

Thanks,
Lev

Comment: I'd suggest that you first diagnose this problem a bit further: is it really working slow only on the server, or might it be that it is running fast only on your computer? Is it generally working slow under Windows 2003 server or only on the specific server you've installed it at?
Also, diagnose exactly what part of your code is time-consuming: use Trace output of some sort (writing to a text file is sufficient) that reports the timestamp each sub-routine started at, and see if you can pinpoint the slow sub-routine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there's some network latency that's present from your server and not from your desktop/workstation? Maybe there's memory/resource contention that's present on the server but not on your workstation. Also, is the code doing EXACTLY the same thing on your workstation that it does from the server? Accessing the same databases (for example, you're not comparing performance between a local development database and your production database server)?

I'd recommend that you try the process from some additionaly loctions, if you have access to them. Maybe another Windows Server 2003 box? See if the problem is isolated to that single server, or if it occurs anywhere that isn't your development workstation.

If you're open to installing one, I'd recommend a profiling tool tool to help you identify the section of your application that's running slowly on the server - [Redgate ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm) is an outstanding code profiler, and they have a 30-day demo (though the price is reasonable and I'd highly recommend any of their tools).